# pages are not redirected to https in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, https

when I type any suburl like www.example.com/abc in chrome, it is redirected to https://www.example.com as it should be but not in firefox. However site url example.com or www.example.com works fine in both browser (redirects to https). My wordpress website old url was https://example.com. I made it https://www.example.com just by setting in wordpress settings page. Don't know this may also the cause of this issue or not. My htaccess file code is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```